# SQL bigint data type seen as string by gettype(); function. why?

Tags: php, sqldatatypes, bigint

1) I want to understand why numeric data stored as `bigint` is seen as `'string'` when i call `gettype();` in php.

2) Is there a function such as `is_bigint();` for php that can check if variable is bigint.

3) How can i check data type when it's bigint as multiplying by 1 OR adding 0 to a string mixed with numbers and alphabets will retrun `'Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 2'` and calling `gettype();` on the now multiplied data type will return:`integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that PHP has no bigint type. The database driver, or wherever you're getting that value from, is giving you your data as a string, because that's the only reliable way to represent the value.

On a 64-bit system, PHP's int type should be a signed 64-bit integer; but on a 32-bit system, it will be 32-bit, so your values would not fit. You can double check by echoing the `PHP_INT_MAX` [built-in constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), which gives you the maximum value you can store in an integer on your build of PHP.

To tell if the value is all digits, you can use `ctype_digit($value)`, but this won't work for negative numbers since `-` is not a digit. The best way I know of is using a regex, e.g. `preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+/', $value)`.

If your values fit (i.e. are between `PHP_INT_MIN` and `PHP_INT_MAX`), you can just cast the string to an integer with `(int)$value` or `intval($value)`, no need for tricks like `+0` or `*1`.

If they don't, you'll need to either handle them as floats, which is what PHP does if the result of an operation is too large for an integer, but means storing them imprecisely; or use an arbitrary-precision maths module like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) or [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Comment: okay i understand thanks, i will check if each character in the string is a number then cast the string to int but will `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` cast as integer ?

Comment: @BobbyAxe If your string has commas in like that, then no, it won't cast directly to the correct value. But I'd be very surprised if a database driver gave you back a string like that. If you just mean "is it too big", look at the value of the PHP_INT_MAX constant I mentioned.

Comment: i meant with out the commas Eg: `9223372036854775807` and PHP_INT_MAX returns `2147483647`

Comment: @BobbyAxe Well, there's your answer then: on your system, the maximum value you can store in an integer is 2147483647.